# Excluding an html part from being clicked

Tags: html

I have a certain container and when you click on it, some javascrip is executed.
Within this container, I have a button.

How can I make that when you click anywhere on that container, the code is executed EXCEPT on the button?

```
<div id="container" onclick="alert('hello');">
    ...
    <input type="button" value="button">
    ...
</div>
```

The only way I found was to place the button outside the container and adjust its absolut position. But maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Have a click handler on the button where you stop the click from propagating to containing div. Also, google "javascript event bubbling"

Comment: if you will want to use the button as a button and when it is clicked then run another function, you should implement on the container a onClick function and check for the event source to not be the button => run, if it is the button just use event.stopPropagation() and then the same principle on the onClick button function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `event.stopPropagation()`, like this:

```
<div style="width: 500px;height:500px;" onclick="alert(1);">
     ...
         <button type="button" value="button" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
     ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that this is how event propagation works:
when you click on something, the event goes into the parent element as long as they have click event listeners. You prevent that from happening, use

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

For more info see: http://eloquentjavascript.net/14_event.html

Comment: and not only to the parent, but it propagates all the up the ancestors DOM tree. Also such elements do not necessarily need an event listener in order to bubble child events...

Comment: they do not, but the events will be triggered if they do, that is what I meant

Comment: well... I suppose you understand how events propagate, but your answer as its currently written is a bit misleading ;)